# Finding the function of a graph with sharp peaks and an exponentially increasing period

Tags: computer-science, graphing-functions

*Context:*
I'm a secondary student working on a small exploration of the [fast inverse square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) algorithm. This algorithm uses a certain constant to "tune" the approximation to a small margin of error. Out of curiosity, I tried setting the value of the fast inverse square root equal to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ for several values of $x$ in order to solve for a better constant that would completely eliminate the error at each point.

*The issue:*
Plotting the results against $x$ leads to the graphs below. I've attached one version with a linear scale, and one with a logarithmic scale on the $x$-axis.

[image: - [Graph with linear scale;][2]]
[image: - [Graph with semi-logarithmic scale.][3]]

I am currently struggling to find a function that would produce this type of relationship. The process I used to generate the data involved some computer memory hacking (reinterpreting the bits of a `float` as a `long` and vice-versa), which is difficult to express mathematically.

However, the graph doesn't seem too outlandish. It has a repeating pattern, though the "period" quadruples each cycle. It has two distinct "peaks", with the low one occurring when $x$ is an odd power of $2$ and the high one on even powers of $2$.

I've done some tinkering but I don't feel that I've made any significant progress; $-|\cos{(\pi\cdot4^\frac{1}{x})}|$ has been my best guess and it's not remotely close. I would appreciate any help expressing this relationship in mathematical terms.

This is my first time asking, so I'll do my best to provide additional information and fix mistakes as needed.

Comment: I pasted in the graphs for you and deleted the sentence that said you couldn't.  Please review and update as you like.  It is not clear to me where the decimal point goes on the vertical axis.  You could provide the exact function that is plotted.

Comment: Easiest solution would probably be to approximate each of the two repeating „valleys“ with a polynomial and then to define the function piecewise. (And then to add some scaling in the argument because of the decreasing „period“). But I’ve no idea if that’s a practical solution for your use case.

Comment: To start, the second graph suggests you want a periodic function of $\log_2 x$, not a periodic function of $4^{1/x}$.

Comment: Or you could use nonlinear regression to estimate the parameters of a model like: $\min (u_1sin(\log_2(x)u_2+u_3), u_4sin(\log_2(x)u_5+u_6))$ You can do that for example using scipy.optimize.leastsq in python

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks for your help. To clarify, there's no decimal point. Because the values are so high, I've truncated the y-axis. The graph was created from a dataset and the script used to generate it involves some bit-level hacking for which there's no equivalent mathematical operation, so I believe I'll need to find an approximation.

Comment: Concerning the idea behind your question, you are not going to find such a constant. The IEEE storage format trick will with rare exceptions only get you within the general vicinity of the root, and the following interation of a root finding algorithm can only improve it so much. You might be able to find a constant that will perform slightly better than the indicated one, but there is no constant that is perfect. Also, be aware that this technique is now only used on low-end machines, as modern processors have built-in square root circults that are faster and more accurate.